# SwiftyJSON print all values in an array of dictionaries

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swifty-json

I have a dictionary array:

```
var dictArray = [[String:String]]()
```

I append a few dictionaries and turn `dictArray` into JSON:

```
let json = JSON(dictArray)
```

Then I encounter trouble trying to actually print these values in JSON format with this loop:

```
for (index,subJson):(String, JSON) in json {
    print(index)
}
```

The above loop is taken from the SwiftyJSON documentation but it doesn't seem to be working for me. I want the output to look like this:

```
 {
"dictArray": [
  {
  "a": "a stuff 1",
  "b": "b stuff 1",
  "c": "c stuff 1",
  "d": "d stuff 1"
},
{
  "a": "a stuff 2",
  "b": "b stuff 2",
  "c": "c stuff 2",
  "d": "d stuff 2"
},
{
  "a": "a stuff 3",
  "b": "b stuff 3",
  "c": "c stuff 3",
  "d": "d stuff 3"
    }
  ]
}
```

All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to iterate the dictionary to print it. You could simply print it with `print(json)`

If you want to loop the dictionary, you should go with something like this:

```
for dictionaries in json {
    for (key, value) in dictionaries {
        print("\(key): \(value)")
    }
}
```

Comment: This code gives me the following errors: `Error: type 'JSONGenerator.Element' (aka '(String, JSON)') does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'` and `type 'JSONGenerator.Element' (aka '(String, JSON)') does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'`

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this :

```
var array = [String:[[String:String]]]()

var dictArray = [[String:String]]()

var stuffArray1 = [String: String]()
stuffArray1["a"] = "a stuff 1"
stuffArray1["b"] = "b stuff 1"
stuffArray1["c"] = "c stuff 1"
stuffArray1["d"] = "d stuff 1"
dictArray.append(stuffArray1)

var stuffArray2 = [String: String]()
stuffArray2["a"] = "a stuff 2"
stuffArray2["b"] = "b stuff 2"
stuffArray2["c"] = "c stuff 2"
stuffArray2["d"] = "d stuff 2"
dictArray.append(stuffArray2)

var stuffArray3 = [String: String]()
stuffArray3["a"] = "a stuff 3"
stuffArray3["b"] = "b stuff 3"
stuffArray3["c"] = "c stuff 3"
stuffArray3["d"] = "d stuff 3"
dictArray.append(stuffArray3)

array["dictArray"] = dictArray

let json = JSON(array)
print(json)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (_, object) in json ?? [] {
  let dict = NSMutableDictionary()
  for(key, value) in object {
      dict.setValue(value.stringValue, forKey: key)
     // all the values must be *String*, otherwise this fails.
  }

  print(dict)
}
```